# Issues when applying list of indices to a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix

I am interested in generating a 1D list of the upper-triangle elements of a matrix.

I can grab the indices of these elements by doing:

```
upperTrianglularIndices[dim_] := Subsets[Table[i, {i, val /. val -> dim}], {2}];
```

But I'm struggling to actually select the matrix elements using these indices.

If I have a function, then I know I can map-thread it using this code:

```
f @@ # & /@ upperTrianglularIndices[3]
```

which will return:

```
{f[1, 2], f[1, 3], f[2, 3]}
```

so my idea is to express my matrix as a function, function[matrix[[x]],x], and then use the above code to apply it to each index. I see that this works correctly like this:

```
(x \[Function] f[[x]]) @@ # & /@ upperTrianglularIndices[3]
```

But doesn't work when I specify that I want the function to be the selection of the matrix element:

```
(x \[Function] {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}[[x]]) @@ # & /@ 
 upperTrianglularIndices[3]
```

This returns (with some errors):

```
{f[[1]], f[[1]], f[[2]]}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: You could try using an undocumented internal function: ``Statistics`Library`UpperTriangularMatrixToVector[f]``

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @yarchik, the upper triangle (with or without diagonals) made to be a vector. So in this case, {2, 3, 6} or {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9}

Comment: @CarlWoll, I'm primarily interested in improving so my preference would be to learn how to do this using the basic syntax - but in the future, (when I'm confident but lazy) I would be interested in using that undocumented internal function. Do you happen to know if there's another command that grabs the diagonal elements too?

Comment: Diagonal returns the diagonal elements.

Comment: @CarlWoll, thanks but unfortunately that shuffles around the order of the elements - which is not ideal in my situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take upper triangular part of matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185690/take-upper-triangular-part-of-matrix)

Comment: @yarchik, I want to extract the upper triangular part of a square matrix into a flat list. (Ideally, I would like this list to be organized such that elements are picked from the top-left first).  I am particularly interested in what exactly is the issue in the logic with my attempt.

Comment: @CarlWoll, it is helpful to see someone elses attempt with it. But I notice that his methods seem pretty substantially different than mine, and I wonder why a method like this (where you mapthread a list to the Part function) doesn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[f[m_, n_]] := Subscript[f, m, n]

n = 3;

(mat = Array[f, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The indices are

```
upperTrianglularIndices[n_] :=
 Table[{i, j}, {i, n}, {j, i, n}] // Flatten[#, 1] &

upperTrianglularIndices[n]

(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}} *)
```

The corresponding elements of the array are

```
mat[[##]] & @@@ upperTrianglularIndices[n]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. One question: how do you think about when to use # or ##?

Comment: `#` takes the first argument, `##` takes all arguments.